# Vuforia virtual button does not work

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying some samples with Vuforia virtual buttons. The problem is times, when my hand cover these buttons it does not work. I have nothing to put as code here because I have nothing to code; just put a console log when it trigger the default hover function.

What are the factors that can influence the accuracy of these virtual buttons. The problem is it sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't work (cannot recognize that my hands are hovering on these buttons).

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow all the rules as posted in the instructions here: [How To Implement Virtual Buttons](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Implement-Virtual-Buttons)? Also, make sure the buttons cover enough features.